# Can I do complex tag searches?

Tags: discussion, tags, search, faq-proposed

This is a bit (or maybe a lot) specific, but I want

```
+[retag-request] -[status-completed] -[status-declined]
```

...if you see what I mean, to look for straggling retags.

I'm just wondering if there is anything I can put in the search to get this. But it isn't worth writing anything extra (i.e. this *isn't* a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)), as it isn't too hard to look through them manually (and there are better things to spend development time on).

Comment: Don't they give you, like, a thousand page manual with stuff like this that you have to study and write a two-day test about before they give you that shiny little diamond next to your name?

Comment: It sure ain't shiny no more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do:

[Yes to <kbd>retag-request</kbd>, no to <kbd>status-completed</kbd> and no to <kbd>status-declined</kbd>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request+-status-declined+-status-completed).

Comment: Cheers - I had too few -s ;-p

Comment: is it possible to do the following kind of query -android AND (android-c2dm OR android-view OR android-listview)? If so, how?

Comment: @DirkJäckel type the following in the search box [`[-android][android-c2dm] [or] [-android][android-view] [or] [-android][android-listview]`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/-android+android-c2dm+or+-android+android-view+or+-android+android-listview). See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137265/search-for-questions-tagged-a-and-also-tagged-b-or-c/137276#137276) for details