# Excluding tags from search results

Tags: support, tags, search

I'd like to be able to do the following in the search box:

```
shell [cmd] [-linux]
```

to search for "**questions containing the 'shell' *term* AND having the 'cmd' tag AND NOT having the 'linux' tag**"

Note that "shell" is not a TAG !

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/can-i-do-complex-tag-searches

Comment: It is not a duplicate, as I want to be able to do a keyword+tags search, not only tags

Comment: Okay, then quote the terms and bracket the tags

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can if you [precede the tag in the search with a minus (-)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/can-i-do-complex-tag-searches):

```
shell [cmd] -[linux]
```

The following links pop for searches across the SOFU for questions that mention *shell* tagged  [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) but **not** tagged [linux](/questions/tagged/linux).

StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=shell+%5Bcmd%5D+-%5Blinux%5D

ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/search?q=shell+%5Bcmd%5D+-%5Blinux%5D

SuperUser: https://superuser.com/search?q=shell+%5Bcmd%5D+-%5Blinux%5D

Comment: I think the minus sign should be outside the brackets, Is it right?
I tried and it is the solution. OK

Comment: Logically it would be on the outside, but within the brackets, it keeps that part of the query as a tag.

Answer (score 2):

As workaround you can set `linux` to your ignore list temporarily (or permanently, if you don't like it at all).