# Searching for text and -tag does NOT work

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search

I searched for a way to search for some text and filter out a tag. That should be possible right? I think it should.
I found different answers, suggesting to add a minus [before the brackets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46060/tag-search-not-operator-is-broken), or [inside the brackets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/can-we-have-the-ability-to-filter-out-a-certain-tag-in-the-search), or [that YMMV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31252/not-statement-search-searching-for-posts-in-a-certain-tag-but-not-in-another-tag). Well, [both](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=help+-%5bbatch%5d) [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=help+%5b-batch%5d) don't work.

[Inside the brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=help+%5b-batch%5d) seems to be the 'right' way, as it shows on the right:

> posts containing
>   **help**
>   within these tags
>   not `batch`

However, this gives me all questions containing the word `help` **and** the tag `batch`. All results do have the tag `batch`! :-(

[Only using tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/help+-batch) does work, but that's not what I need.

The proper behavior [is not documented](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

Am I missing something? Or is it just broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test -[tag]` scenario has been supported since our latest search engine changes, so your search attempt of `help -[batch]` [now works](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=help+-%5bbatch%5d).

Note: we still don't support ***only*** a negative tag with no other search criteria...that's just millions of results helping no one.

Comment: Great! Except that searching for `-[batch]` should *say* that it doesn't work (and why).