# Excluding tags from job listings

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Scenario is very simple. I'm not an expert in every language/platform. For example I really don't know C++ and view C++ job postings is useless for me. This applies to Ruby and Python too, as I'm expert in C#, Java, SQL with all the respect to people working on Ruby, Python, C, F#...

Question comes straightforward: why not allowing candidates to exclude tags from job searches? Why not using tags in their profiles to customize search results?

I have tried [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/excluding-tags-from-search-results) but `cloud -[c++]` doesn't show me cloud-related jobs that are **not** `c++`-tagged

Answer (score 1):

You can do [this](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=ruby+-c%2B%2B) instead.

We don’t use a tag syntax for searching on Careers. Everything is effectively a full-text search, and we do have basic Boolean support.