# Update the Advanced Search Page to include the "complex tag searches"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

I was wondering how to exclude tags on my searches, tried to find this option on the Advanced Super Ninja Search Options and failed.

But when I was about to create a feature-request for this, I found that [it is actually possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16463/179635)

Please include it somewhere in the Advanced Super Ninja Search Options

Comment: So what we're missing is a callout for the ability to use the `-` (not) operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated [the comprehensive search help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to include this operator:

> - To *exclude* results from a tag, term or phrase, prefix it with `-` in your query: `waffles -unicorns` finds posts that mention tasty batter-based breakfasts without including mythical creatures, while `[laurel] -[hardy]` includes only posts pertaining to the first half of the classic comedy couple.