# Search for questions tagged [A] and also (tagged [B] or [C])

Tags: support, tags, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advanced Search Options Syntax: Multiple Tags, And Vs. Or](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33099/advanced-search-options-syntax-multiple-tags-and-vs-or)

I have looked around meta and found xyz "search tags" questions but could find one that solves my problem and I would appreciate if someone could point me out in direction that could solve my problem.

I am trying following:
I want to search for questions tagged [A] **and** also (tagged [B] **or** [C]).  So for example I would like to see all questions tagged [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) or [android](/questions/tagged/android) that also have been tagged [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface).

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One quick solution I can think of is temporarily setting your favorite tags to [tag:ios] and [tag:android] and then searching [tag:user-interface]. The posts you're looking for will be highlighted in friendly yellow.

Comment: @gobernador: Is it possible not to show the other results, i.e. just show highlighted ones? Such that only the ones from favorite tags show up?

Comment: I can't find any way to do this. +1 for you.

Comment: I hope someone does. I really hope.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: You have voted to close this question as a duplicate. Could you kindly point me to an answer in [the duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33099/advanced-search-options-syntax-multiple-tags-and-vs-or) that shows how to do both `AND` and `OR` on tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41681/181088) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/33099/181088) led me to a good answer that I don't believe is a complete solution, but it works. if your tag are `A`, plus `B` or `C`, you would type into the search bar:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/A%20B%20OR%20A%20C
```

Your particular solution will be

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface%20android%20OR%20user-interface%20ios

That is, to AND them, include `%20`, and to OR them, include `%20OR%20`. The problem with the current situation is that the search bar currently replaces  , a space, with `+` before searching. Therefore, when you type a search, all the words are ANDed together. [`%20` represents a space in a URL](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm). I don't believe this will change unless the search bar is modified fundamentally.

You can, however, get this functionality in a search bar by going to https://stackoverflow.com/search and using the Google search box. Typing `user-interface android OR user-interface ios` yields [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=user-interface+android+OR+user-interface+ios&sitesearch=stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions), which contains all the questions you're looking for.

EDIT: It appears from [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/) that you can actually type spaces into the address bar, as in

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface android OR user-interface ios
```

rather than messing with the kludgy hex code. I would like to see this changed in the way that the search box works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buser-interface%5D+%28+%5Bandroid%5D+or+%5Bios%5D+%29&submit=search

Comment: Hats down to @gobernador! Total respect.

Answer (score 7):

`(A && (B||C)) == ((A&&B) || (A&&C))`

If you're using the search box, use the search terms: `[A][B] [or] [A][C]`. This will redirect you to [/questions/tagged/a+b+or+a+c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a+b+or+a+c).

Using your example, searching for [[user-interface][android] [or] [user-interface][ios]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface+android+or+user-interface+ios) gives us:

[image: Search result]

---

Related post: [Search [tag1] OR [tag2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)

Comment: This works too. Thanks for your post.